# Python regex group extraction

Tags: python, regex

For this string:

```
"https://webster.bfm.com/viewserver/rw?port=AAA-NY&rpttag=praada_pnl_sum_eq.BMACS_ASST_ALL&subdir=gp_views/MUS-ALLRET/released"
```

looking to run regular expression to look like the below:

```
list = [port=AAA,rpttag=praada_pnl_sum_eq.BMACS_ASST_ALL,subdir=gp_views/MUS-ALLRET/released]
```

I got this so far:

```
re.findall(r'\?(.+)','https://webster.bfm.com/viewserver/rw?port=AAA-NY&rpttag=praada_pnl_sum_eq.BMACS_ASST_ALL&subdir=gp_views/MUS-ALLRET/released')
```

that just returns one string. I know I need to just repeat this pattern, \S&+ using [], but can't see to figure out the best way to do this all in one regex

Answer (score 0):

```
re.findall(r'[^?&]+', s)[1:]
```

This works by splitting on either `?` or `&` and then throwing away the first match, which is the part up to the `?`.

I'm making two assumptions here: first, that there are no `?` characters in your fragments, and second, that you really want the first element of your list to be `port=AAA-NY`.

Comment: ahhh thank you. your assumptions are corrrect. So let me get this straight.  ^ = starts with.. so repeat the pattern of "Starts with ? to &", but not every fragment has a "?".. and im understanding this correctly?

Comment: Normally `^` does mean "starts with", however inside `[...]` its meaning changes to "not".  So `[^?&]` matches any character that is not `?` or `&`.

Comment: oh ? = referring to match 0 or 1 occurances of the patters to its left... I think i got it now

Comment: The `?` inside [...] has no special meaning; it refers to the literal `?` in your URL string.

Comment: hmm I guess I'm confused on how this is working then..is it saying the range of ? to &

Comment: The regex matches all the text between any `?` or `&`, thus splitting your string on those delimiters. Look up the meaning of the `[` character for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Using regex to parse URL is a bad idea when Python has built-in library to do the job:

#### Python 3

Use [`urlparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlparse) to parse the URL into schema, port, host, query, etc., then use [`parse_qs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.parse_qs) to parse the query string.

Do check out the documentation for parsing options for corner cases.

Example code:

```
from urllib.parse import *
input = 'https://webster.bfm.com/viewserver/rw?port=AAA-NY&rpttag=praada_pnl_sum_eq.BMACS_ASST_ALL&subdir=gp_views/MUS-ALLRET/released'
url = urlparse(input)
query_parts = parse_qs(url.query)
```

Printing `query_parts`:

```
>>> print(query_parts)
{'rpttag': ['praada_pnl_sum_eq.BMACS_ASST_ALL'], 'port': ['AAA-NY'], 'subdir': ['gp_views/MUS-ALLRET/released']}
```

#### Python 2

The code in Python 2.* is similar, but you need to import [`urlparse`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#module-urlparse) module, instead of `urllib.parse`. The functions are more or less the same.